# VS2012 keyboard shortcut for "expand selection to tag"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a keyboard shortcut / free extension in Visual Studio 2012 to extend the selection to the logical code block?

For example when editing HTML, I'd like to be able to put my cursor in an opening tag and select to the matching closing tag, including all elements nested inside.

Sublime Text 2 has an "Expand Selection to Tag" option (Ctrl + Shift + A) for this purpose.

Thanks

Comment: There is a command for this, under Edit -> Advanced -> Select Tag... but it seems to be disabled, even in the HTML editor, when the cursor is inside a tag!  Appaprently, this was also an issue in 2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086968/visual-studio-select-tag-command-doesnt-work

Comment: Hmm... the "tag navigator" at the bottom of the HTML editor allows you to click on any of the enclosing tag names and selects the "outerHtml" for that tag, but I can't find a menu/keyboard command that exposes the same functionality.  (In part, probably because the command wouldn't know _which_ of the enclosing tags you're trying to select.)

Comment: Jared - thanks very much for your replies. The tag navigator at the bottom of the HTML editor actually does a good job of this... Just goes to show that sometimes the simplest solutions are staring you right in the face! I'll keep looking for keyboard shortcuts and post back if I find anything, but in the mean time this will be really useful (still a lot faster than manual selection!) Cheers again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JaredReisinger who pointed out that the "tag navigator" at the bottom of the HTML editor allows this kind of functionality, albeit with the mouse rather than the keyboard.